# Get the unique longest common prefix element info from array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to fetch the unique longest common substring element information from an array.

```
String arr[] = { 
"/partA/partB/partC/value1",
"/partA/partB/partC/value2",
"/partD/partE/partF/value1",
"/partD/partE/partF/value2",
"/partG/partH/partI/value1",
"/partG/value2",
"/partJ/value1" 
}
```

From the input array, the first 2 elements are common until "/partA/partB/partC", so I need to fetch the common value. Like wise, the 3rd and 4th elements have the common value as "/partD/partE/partF" the 5th and 6th have the common value as /partG," and the 7th doesn't have any common value with the other elements, so it should print as "/partJ/value1."  The final output should be mentioned below,

```
[ "/partA/partB/partC",
  "/partD/partE/partF",
  "/partG",
  "/partJ/value1"
]
```

For this, I'm comparing and trying to find the longest common substring, something like below, but  bot getting the desired output.

```
while(idx < s1.length() && idx < s2.length()){
        if(s1.charAt(idx) == s2.charAt(idx)){
            idx++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
     }
     s1.substring(0, idx);
```

Comment: Use a sliding window approach. Start from both ends and work towards the center. If two items match, you don't have to proceed further.

Comment: This seems underspecified. If you go strictly by strings, then the first common value would surely have to be "/partA/partB/partC/value", and the last one "/". So is there more to what you want? Comparing pairs of strings? Matching by delimiters?

Comment: Yeah, it's matching string by delimiter '/'

Comment: But your code is not considering that. So this is one problem with it.

Comment: What's the overall goal of the problem you're describing here? Be wary of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). It looks like you are maybe trying to break these down into some kind of tree structure? If so, a literal `Tree<String>` may service you well, or making your own by hand. Barring the `value1` bit in the output, you're looking essentially at "branches" of a tree with no leaves (end-nodes).

Comment: These all have a longest common prefix of `"/part"`, why isn't that the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tokenize all the paths, loop over each path, and for each path, loop through the other paths.

Just compare them at index 1 and work your way to the right until they no longer match. Store the path inside of a set.

Based on your desired output, you want a common path for each of the first parts i.e., `partA`, `partD`, `partG`, and `partJ`.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class LongestCommonPath {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String arr[] = {
        "/partA/partB/partC/value1", "/partA/partB/partC/value2",
        "/partD/partE/partF/value1", "/partD/partE/partF/value2",
        "/partG/partH/partI/value1", "/partG/value2",
        "/partJ/value1"
    };

    for (String path : longestCommonPaths(1, "/", arr)) {
      System.out.println(path);
    }
  }

  public static List<String> longestCommonPaths(int offset, String delimiter, String... paths) {
    Set<String> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    List<List<String>> tokenizedPaths = Stream.of(paths).map(path -> tokenizePath(path, delimiter)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (List<String> currPath : tokenizedPaths) {
      boolean found = false;
      for (List<String> otherPath : tokenizedPaths) {
        if (currPath != otherPath && currPath.get(offset).equals(otherPath.get(offset))) {
          result.add(commonPath(currPath, otherPath).stream().collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter)));
          found = true;
        }
      }
      if (!found) {
        result.add(currPath.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter)));
        found = false;
      }
    }
    return new ArrayList<>(result);
  }

  private static List<String> commonPath(List<String> path, List<String> otherPath) {
    int index = 0;
    while (index < path.size() && index < otherPath.size() && path.get(index).equals(otherPath.get(index))) {
      index++;
    }
    return path.subList(0, index);
  }

  private static List<String> tokenizePath(String path, String delimiter) {
    return Stream.of(path.split(delimiter)).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

### Output

```
/partA/partB/partC
/partD/partE/partF
/partG
/partJ/value1
```

Comment: I would use _Stream.of(paths).map(string -> List.of(string.split("/"))).toList()_ instead of the _tokenizePath_ method.  Additionally, you could use _result.add(String.join(delimiter, commonPath(currPath, otherPath)))_.  On a final note, you should move the boolean _found_ declaration to outside of the _loop_.  Otherwise, nice work, it functions well.

Comment: Pay attention on the complexity of this solution. This is `O(nˆ2)` which is not good.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I'm trying to fetch the unique longest common substring element information from an array. ..."*

> *"... From the input array, the first 2 elements are common until "/partA/partB/partC", so I need to fetch the common value. ..."*

So, the longest common prefix of each value.
You'll need additional code; a "longest common prefix" code will return one value, in this case "/part".

You'll need to traverse *arr* and additionally sub-traverse the other items.
In this example the prefix value is added to a *[List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)*, and then removed when a longer *string* is found.
I then added the list to a *[Set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html)*, to remove any duplicate values.

```java
String arr[] = {
    "/partA/partB/partC/value1",
    "/partA/partB/partC/value2",
    "/partD/partE/partF/value1",
    "/partD/partE/partF/value2",
    "/partG/partH/partI/value1",
    "/partG/value2",
    "/partJ/value1"
};
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
String string;
int maximum;
for (int a = 0, b; a < arr.length; a++) {
    maximum = 0;
    for (b = 0; b < arr.length; b++) {
        if (a == b) continue;
        string = longestCommonPrefix(arr[a], arr[b]);
        if (string.length() > maximum) {
            if (maximum != 0) list.remove(list.size() - 1);
            list.add(string);
            maximum = string.length();
        }
    }
    if (maximum == 0) list.add(arr[a]);
}
new TreeSet<>(list).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I'm using a "longest common prefix" routine from *Google AI*; it's similar to what you have.
I've adjusted it to check for a `/`, since you're looking to evaluate each field of the delimited values.
In other words, if it's not the entire value, return up to the last `/` character of the prefix.

```java
String longestCommonPrefix(String a, String b) {
    int index, length = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
    for (index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        if (a.charAt(index) != b.charAt(index)) break;
    }
    if (index == a.length()) return a.substring(0, index);
    else {
        int indexOf = a.substring(0, index).lastIndexOf('/');
        if (indexOf != -1) return a.substring(0, indexOf);
        else return a.substring(0, 1);
    }
}
```

Output

```
/partA/partB/partC
/partD/partE/partF
/partG
/partJ/value1
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be done with `O(nlogn)` complexity using search tree data structure.

```java
public static List<String> findCommonPrefix(String... paths) {
    Node root = buildTree(paths);
    return dfs(root);
}

private static List<String> dfs(Node root) {
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    Deque<String> stack = new LinkedList<>();

    for (Node node : root.children.values())
        dfs(node, stack, res);

    return res;
}

private static void dfs(Node node, Deque<String> queue, List<String> res) {
    queue.add(node.data);

    if (node.children.size() == 1)
        dfs(node.children.values().iterator().next(), queue, res);
    else
        res.add(queue.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("/", "/", "")));
    
    queue.remove();
}

private static Node buildTree(String... paths) {
    Node root = new Node("/");

    for (String path : paths)
        addNode(root, path.split("/"), 1);
   

    return root;
}

private static Node addNode(Node parent, String[] parts, int i) {
    if (parts.length > i) {
        Node node = parent.children.computeIfAbsent(parts[i], Node::new);
        return addNode(node, parts, i + 1);
    }

    return parent;
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
private static final class Node {

    private final String data;
    private final Map<String, Node> children = new HashMap<>();

}
```

**Output:**

```
/partA/partB/partC
/partD/partE/partF
/partG
/partJ/value1
```